# IF $f\in L^1[0,1]$ satisfies $\int_0^1 fg^{(n)}dx=0$ for all smooth $g$ supported in $(0,1)$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $V$ be the space of infinitely differentiable real-valued functions $[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ supported in $(0,1)$. For some fixed positive integer $n$ and a function $f\in L^1[0,1]$, I am asked to show that if the integral $\int_0^1 fg^{(n)}dx=0$ for all $g\in V$ where $g^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $g$, then $f$ must be a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$.

It seems that it suffices to show that $f^{(n)}=0$, but I can't see how to show that $f$ is differentiable. Can I get a hint for this problem?

Comment: if $f\in C^n$ then $\int_{0}^1f g^{(n)}=(-1)^{n}\int_{0}^1f^{(n)}g
$ by integration by parts. For general $f\in L^1$ it seems that you need to prove the same using the distributional derivative.